# Converting audio from ByteBuffer (from exoplayer) to float* (IPLFloat32) and back for processing

Tags: java, c++, audio, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I am writing a custom AudioProcessor for ExoPlayer (in kotlin/Java) that takes the incoming audio data, passes it to the Steam Audio API (in C++), processes it using `iplApplyBinauralEffect` and passes it back to ExoPlayer. The problem comes when the ByteBuffer that ExoPlayer provides from `queueInput` needs to be converted to the float* (IPLfloat32) that Steam expects. How do I convert a ByteBuffer to a float* that Steam will process?

The ByteBuffer says it's little endian, so I converted to big endian, but it's still returning massive and tiny values.

[The docs for Steam Audio API are here](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steam-audio/doc/capi/index.html)
[and the docs for ExoPlayer are here](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/)

the audio buffer [IPLAudioBuffer is described here](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steam-audio/doc/capi/struct_i_p_l_audio_buffer.html)

(passed from the AudioProcessor subclass)

```java
    public ByteBuffer queueInput(ByteBuffer inputBuffer, ByteBuffer buffer, int position, int length) {
        //inputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        FloatBuffer floatBuffer = inputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asFloatBuffer();
        float[] input = new float[floatBuffer.limit()];
        floatBuffer.get(input);
        // get rendered output
        float[] convertedArray = queueInput(playerIndex, input, floatBuffer.limit());
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(inputBuffer.limit() * 2);
        FloatBuffer outputFloatBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
        outputFloatBuffer.put(convertedArray);
        buffer.rewind();
        return buffer;
    }
```

(via jni)

```cpp
    queueInput(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint playerIndex, jfloatArray bytes, jint len) {
    jfloat *input = env->GetFloatArrayElements(bytes, nullptr);
    int inputaudio = engine->getOutput(static_cast<unsigned int>(playerIndex), input, len, input);
    jfloatArray result;
    result = env->NewFloatArray(inputaudio);
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, inputaudio, input);

    free(input);
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(bytes, input, JNI_COMMIT);
    return result;
    }
```

(passed to SteamPlayer)

```cpp
    int SteamPlayer::getOutput(float *input, int len, float *output) {
        std::vector<float> outputaudioframe(static_cast<unsigned int>(2 * framesize));
        std::vector<float> outputaudio;

        int numFrames = len / framesize;

        IPLAudioBuffer inbuffer{ stereo, framesize, input };
        inbuffer.format.numSpeakers = 2;
        inbuffer.format.speakerDirections = &inDirections;

        IPLAudioBuffer outbuffer{stereo, framesize, outputaudioframe.data()};
        outbuffer.format.numSpeakers = 2;
        outDirections.x = x;
        outDirections.y = y;
        outDirections.z = z;
        outbuffer.format.speakerDirections = &outDirections;

        for (auto i = 0; i < numFrames; ++i) {
            iplApplyBinauralEffect(effect, renderer, inbuffer, outDirections, IPL_HRTFINTERPOLATION_NEAREST, outbuffer);
            std::copy(std::begin(outputaudioframe), std::end(outputaudioframe), std::back_inserter(outputaudio));
            inbuffer.interleavedBuffer += framesize;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < outputaudio.size(); ++i) {
            outputaudio[i] *= 32767;
        }
        std::memcpy(output, outputaudio.data(), outputaudio.size());
        return outputaudio.size();

    }
```

Here is a screenshot of some of the incoming data, just before the 'convertedArray' line

[image: Incoming data]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling `asFloatBuffer()` twice?

Comment: @user207421 just a mistake. I've updated it in the post. I will also add some debugging info that shows the incoming data.